# Task Manager shows more worker processes than the max set

Tags: iis, connection, application-pools, worker-process

I am doing application pooling for a web application used by huge number of users and set web garden with a max of 20 worker processes. But in task manager, I see more processes than the w3wp processes than what I set. The web application uses sessions extensively which is managed by memcached.  Can anyone tell me the areas that I could go wrong to create so many worker processes ? I am finding it difficult to narrow down the reasons for that extordinary number of worker process. ( I set the web garden with Idle timeout - 20 mins, max worker processes - 10 )

Answer (score 1):

If you turn on the "Command Line" view in Task Manager, that'll quickly identify the W3WPs you've got in play.

Most simple explanation is likely that you've got more than one App Pool active on the box.

```
NETSH HTTP SHOW SERVICESTATE
```

would let you easily tie worker processes to a given queue (and count them, by the number of PIDs present for each pool).

There might be more complicated explanations if the app pools are short-lived, or hanging.

(What led you to web gardening in the first place?)